# doubts about storing and processing JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-5

I have to implement a server side code to a **Form Builder** front end component which allows to create Forms through drag and drop, something like in [this link](http://minikomi.github.io/Bootstrap-Form-Builder/)

When the form is created a JSON is generated and has to be stored in the database. From there, then there are two uses, first is to edit an already stored form JSON, and second is to implement the Form in html view using the JSON, so that the users can consume it. The form JSON looks something like this, although the levels get deeper for some form components.

```
[{"name":"UserForm"},
{"id":"txtID","label":"Your Name","placeholder":"your name","helptext":"Please enter your name","required":true,"inputsize":"input-xlarge"},
{"id":"selectID","options":["Cricket","Football"],"inputsize":"input-xlarge","label":"Favorite Game"}]
```

When storing this JSON, I can see two ways and which one to choose is confusing me. Firstly, I can create entity classes representing the JSON, and also separate SQL Server Tables for these entities. So the idea is to create complete entities with relationships representing the JSON hierarchy.

Another is to store the complete JSON in one SQLServer Table string (or similar) field and work on that string for processing.

The first option seems to be fragile, since if the JSON keys change, the database schema has to be updated. The second option can absorb this without requiring any changes in database. But, I am not sure of how to process JSON string as objects in C# code. I will need this for implementing say, **Validation Logic** for any form implementation. So, for example if a **"Name"** key has a value of **"Required"** in JSON, then it has to be validated on server side using c#.

So in short how store JSON, as a string field or as Entities representing the JSON hierarchy.

Comment: Just storing JSON in a database table I would serialise/deserialise it through Json.NET and store it as string. If you don't need to inspect the structure in a query and are just recalling it using a key, a single table with a key and text field should be enough. You are resilient against changes to your object - provided you're changes are backwards compatible which should be easy to monitor with a unit test.

Comment: Which means I also have to override the default asp.net MVC Javascript Serializer with the JSON.net. I am also of the opinion of storing JSON as string now, but do you think I should use JSON.net instead of default Javascript serializer that comes with MVC?

Comment: Everytime :)  - I should be on commission and if Newtonsoft had stock, I would buy them. At some point Microsoft needs to just buy the company and make it defacto.